# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL Even after making required fields null

Tags: database, laravel, controller

I have made all the required fields nullable but still I am getting this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: public_problems.name (SQL: insert into "public_problems" ("answer", "helper_id", "helper_name", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Hey Bro Everythings Gonna be Alright, 2, kakashi, 2020-07-30 07:35:05, 2020-07-30 07:35:05))

**Here's my Database:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('public_problems', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('answer')->nullable();
            $table->integer('helper_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('helper_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('problem');
            $table->string('filled_by');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Model:-**

```
class PublicProblem extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id', 'title', 'problem', 'filled_by', 'helper_id', 'answer', 'helper_name'];

}
```

I have divided this field into 2 functions and they are:- 
**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'problem' => 'required',

      ]);
         PublicProblem::create([
            'title'=>$data['title'],
            'problem'=>$data['problem'],
            'name'=>Auth::user()->name,
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->uuid,

          ]);
         return redirect('/home');
    }

public function answer(Request $request) //The Error Occurs when I try to execute this function 
    {
    

        $data = request()->validate([
            'answer' => 'required',
        ]);

        PublicProblem::create([
            'answer' => $data['answer'],
            'helper_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'helper_name' => Auth::user()->name,
        ]);
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

The error occurs when I try to execute `answer()` function 
Cant figure out what's causing it please help

Comment: the `name` field in not nullable. You are trying to create an `PublicProblem` in your `answer function` you should fill up all the data that is not nullable

Comment: @STA the Fatal Error would be responsible for the GUARD not the SQL

Comment: @STA i am logged in, i think the reason for the error is i should use some insertion method instead of create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: public_problems.name

**Solution:**

The name file in your database is not nullable. If you want to call the create method, you will either have to add `'name' => 'someName'` or you add the `->nullable()` constrained to the name field.

```
PublicProblem::create([
            'answer' => $data['answer'],
            'helper_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'helper_name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'name' => 'someName',
        ]);
```

**Please Note:**

You have some more fields which are not nullable, so the error might happen again for another field. (i commented it below)

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name'); //always needs a value
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); //always needs a value
$table->text('answer')->nullable();
$table->integer('helper_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->string('helper_name')->nullable();
$table->string('title'); //always need a value
$table->text('problem'); //always needs a value
$table->string('filled_by'); //always needs a value
```

Comment: is there any `insert` method that i can use instead of create

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox no it wont be possible as long as the fields are not nullable or have a default value

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox i would make them nullable and in your method validate the required fields and only update the wanted fields..

Comment: So i should keep the whole field nullable and inert the values as required

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox yes, in my opinion that is the way to go

Comment: So i am creating an entry in the `store()` function and what method should i use in my `answer()` function to insert data in rest of the fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218876/discussion-between-aless55-and-anonymous-chatbox).

Answer (score 2):

Error here, your **name**, **title**, **user_id**, **problem**, **filled_by** fields are required, make this filled **nullable** on your migration or you should give a **value** while **insert** into table, otherwise SQL throw an error  :

```
PublicProblem::create([
            'name' => "Name", // Not null
            'title' => "Title"; // Not null
            'problem' => "Problem", // Not null
            'filled_by' => "Filled by", // not null
            'user_id' => "1", // not null
            'answer' => $data['answer'],
            'helper_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'helper_name' => Auth::user()->name,
        ]);
```